# Cloud function access GKE with control plane authorized networks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cloud function that accesses the GKE cluster and gets info about it. Before control plane autorized networks was setuped all worked good with just SA, but after it was setuped obviously CF lost access, how can I add the right network of cloud function to get access? I am trying to do it with Serverless VPC connector, but after adding its subnet CIDR I am not able to access cluster still.

The code part I am using for connection

```
credentials, project = google.auth.default(
      scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

    credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())

    cluster_manager_client = ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
    cluster = cluster_manager_client.get_cluster(name=f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{zone}/clusters/{cluster_id}')

    configuration = client.Configuration()
    configuration.host = f"https://{cluster.endpoint}:443"
    configuration.verify_ssl = False
    configuration.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + credentials.token}
    client.Configuration.set_default(configuration)
```

Comment: If your cloud function is connected to the right VPC through the serverless VPC connector, you should be able to reach the private Ip of the control plane without any authorized network. The authorized network is for allowing public IP/Range

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Double checked configuration, VPC config is correct. I have updated the question with the code that I am using for connection

Comment: Control Plane authorized network only works for Public IP's. VPC Serverless Connector uses a private CIDR. You are probably blocked by the firewall rules. Look into your firewall rules and search for the rule that looks like CLUSTER_NAME-RANDOM_STRING_master. Edit that one and add your VPC Serverless Connector IP Range and port 443 or 6443 (you will to try both)

Comment: When I am adding CIDR 0.0.0.0/0 for control plane cloud function can access it

Comment: Do you use the IP of the control plane or the domain name? If it's a domain name, set the egress to ALL on your cloud functions, it's possible the traffic goes to the internet, and then goes back to the control plane

Comment: I have VPC Connector traffic egress ALL setted

Comment: cluster.endpoint that I am using to connect is the public IP, so I think problem with that, how can I omit using public IP?